# how to insert javascript code into powershell?

Tags: javascript, powershell

I want to assign 3000 lines of javascript code to $variable but I am getting the following error. Even though I put the @ signs at the beginning and the end, it doesn't work and gives an error like the one below. How should I do?

[image: Code review]

Comment: The error is way above what you've shown, apparently on line 4, looks like in a function declaration. Post that as well if you can.

Comment: Hang on, that looks like you're trying to run Javascript in PowerShell?  And when you say "@ signs at the beginning and the end", are you trying to create a here-string to store the JavaScript code? I'm not seeing the closing "@ in what you posted, but here-strings need to have nothing after the opening @" and the closing "@ has to be on a line by itself, not even whitespace.

Comment: Please add the missing information as previous commenters suggested. Copy-paste the code and error message as _text_, [formatted as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Screenshots of text are frowned upon, because these can be hard to read and cannot be searched. If you have trouble with the formatting, we can help with that.

Comment: Also: use a [verbatim here string (single quoted)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#single-quoted-strings): `@' ... '@`